# Read and operate on a TS file using node js

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I am creating a npm library where I need to read the files of the folder from where my library function were invoked from command line and then operate on those files.

By operation I mean to check if a variable exist, if a function exists, modifying variable, function,etc.

The files will be a Typescript files.

Any help on how to proceed will be great.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need some kind of [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) parser like [Esprima](https://esprima.org/) or [babel-parser](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-parser). These tools can parse the content of JS/TS files, build the abstract syntax tree that can be traversed, modified and converted back to the source code.

There's a lot of useful tools available in [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) toolset that simplifies these operations. For example, [babel-traverse](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-traverse) simplifies searching the target statement or expression, [babel-types](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-types) that helps to match the type of the AST nodes and [babel-generator](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-generator) that generates the source code from the AST.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be very difficult to get these answers without *running* the files.

So the best approach is probably to just import the files as usual and see what side-effects running the files had. For example, you can check if a file exported anything.

If this doesn't solve your problem, you will have to parse the files. The best way to do that might be to use the typescript compiler itself:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API

Comment: Thanks Evert. Since all npm.libraries goes to the node modules folder, wouldn't importing a user's file in my library and working on it  amount as bad practice?

Comment: @RohanAgarwal it's pretty hard to say for me whether it's a bad practice, because I don't know what your use-case is. If you're trying to do some static analysis it makes sense what you're doing, but if this is not a developer utility I would question if you're doing the right thing.

I think that question is outside the scope of stack overflow, but if you want to have a conversation feel free to DM me on twitter.